# How do this sentence in query builder

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have a question, i need do this query in query builder:

```
SELECT
ps_orders.id_order,
ps_customer.firstname,
ps_customer.lastname,
ps_customer.email,
ps_address.address1,
ps_address.postcode,
ps_address.city,
ps_address.phone_mobile,
ps_orders.id_order,
ps_orders.reference,
ps_order_detail.product_name,
ps_order_detail.product_quantity,
ps_shop.name AS tienda,
ps_carrier.name AS transportista
FROM
ps_customer
INNER JOIN ps_address ON ps_customer.id_customer = ps_address.id_customer
INNER JOIN ps_orders ON ps_address.id_customer =              
ps_orders.id_customer AND ps_orders.id_address_delivery = 
ps_address.id_address
INNER JOIN ps_order_detail ON ps_orders.id_order = 
ps_order_detail.id_order
INNER JOIN ps_shop ON ps_order_detail.id_shop = ps_shop.id_shop                            
INNER JOIN ps_carrier ON ps_orders.id_carrier = ps_carrier.id_carrier                            
WHERE
ps_orders.id_order =54
```

I did this query in query builder:

```
$naviones=DB::connection('naviones')->table('ps_customer')
                ->join('ps_address','ps_customer.id_customer','=','ps_address.id_customer')
               ->join('ps_orders','ps_address.id_customer','=','ps_orders.id_customer')
                ->join('ps_order_detail','ps_orders.id_order','=','ps_order_detail.id_order')
                ->join('ps_shop','ps_order_detail.id_shop','=','ps_shop.id_shop')
                ->join('ps_carrier','ps_orders.id_carrier','=','ps_carrier.id_carrier')
                ->select('ps_orders.id_address_delivery','ps_orders.id_order','ps_customer.firstname','ps_customer.lastname','ps_customer.email','ps_address.address1',
                    'ps_address.postcode','ps_address.city','ps_address.phone_mobile','ps_orders.id_order','ps_orders.reference',
                    'ps_order_detail.product_name','ps_order_detail.product_quantity','ps_shop.name as tienda','ps_carrier.name as transportista')
                ->where('ps_orders.id_order','=',$idpedido)->get();
```

My question is: How can i do for made this query section?

```
INNER JOIN ps_orders ON ps_address.id_customer =              
ps_orders.id_customer AND ps_orders.id_address_delivery = 
ps_address.id_address
```

I hope that yours will can help me. Thank you.

Comment: You can use callback function inside join function and pass your two equality conditions.

Comment: Hi, do you can made a example? in the documentation i not found any similar

Comment: Check my answer can help you

Comment: I think I solved this. In a moment I tell you if i can solve this

Comment: Sure. It will help to others as well.

Comment: Even you can open this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins and read Advanced Join Clauses topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use join something like this

```
->join('table2 AS b', function($join){
        $join->on('a.field1', '=', 'b.field2')
        ->where('b.field3', '=', true)
        ->where('b.field4', '=', '1');
})
```

in case if you don't want to compare then you can use multiple "on" chained function like below

```
$query->join('ps_orders', function($join)
 {
   $join->on('ps_orders.id', '=', 'ps_address.id_customer')
        ->on('ps_orders.id_address_delivery', '=', 'ps_address.id_address')

 });
```

Comment: Hi thank for response me, this method no work for me, because i need comparate how i do in this query: INNER JOIN ps_orders ON ps_address.id_customer =              
ps_orders.id_customer AND ps_orders.id_address_delivery = 
ps_address.id_address The problem in the example that you tell me is that in "where clausules" is necessary comparate with a value is not posible comparate a fiel with other field

Comment: Hi, yeah, this is the correct answer, i was post the solution but you was write the solution. Thank you everybody

Comment: Also is very important say that if you use the function ($ join) but you need comparate with any value and obtain this value of any variable, you can pass the variable to the function ($ join) using the reserved method "use" for example: function ($ join) use ($ variable) {}); I was need pass a variable to the function ($ join) and i was dont know how do it.

Comment: Yes, I know thats why I just only compare with a table.field value, 1 or true values in my first answer.